# One point compactification for open annulus

Tags: general-topology

Describe the one-point compactification of the open annulus $\{(x,y):1<x^2+y^2<2\}$.

I got the answer from the class, but do not fully understand the answer.

The answer is: the one-point compactification for it is the surface of a ball and identify the South Pole with the North Pole.

The illustration is below:
the open annulus $\{(x,y):1<x^2+y^2<2\}$ is homeomorphic to the surface of ball but without the South Pole and the North Pole. The neighborhood of $\infty$ in the one point compactification space must include both of the poles. Thus we have to identify them as a point. Hence we glue the the South Pole and the North Pole together and get the one-point compactification.

Questions:

1. Why is the open annulus $\{(x,y):1<x^2+y^2<2\}$ homeomorphic to the surface of ball but without the South Pole and the North Pole?
2. Why the one-point compactification is just glue something together because they always are included in the same neighborhood?

Comment: You may dislike the illustration of "the surface of the ball but without the South Pole and the North Pole," so perhaps you will feel more convinced by another sort of illustration.  Consider a torus from which we remove the inner circle, so that the resulting complement is homeomorphic to the open annulus.  We can compactify the resulting open annulus by adding a single point to "replace" that inner circle, or what is equivalent, shrink that inner circle down to a point.

Comment: hm..Remove the inner circle of a torus? The inner circle means ${(x,y,z):z=0,x2+y2=1}$? If so, why do the resulting complement is homeomorphic to the open annulus?

Comment: You are splitting the torus open along a seam that runs around the inside circle around the center of the torus.  The result can then be "flattened out" into an open annulus.

Comment: I get your point here. Then how could you know the one-point compactification is equivalent to the inner circle crushing into a point? I mean from the basic understanding of one point compactification, which is space X itself with $\infty$ , denote as $X^+$ and the topology on it  are the open sets in X and the neighborhoods of $\infty$ are the complement of compact sets in X .

Comment: Review the definition of the one-point compactification.  What are the neighborhoods of the one new point we add (to a locally compact topology)?  If you think about it for an hour or so and it doesn't "dawn" for you, I'll post an Answer.

Comment: Now I get a fully intuitive understanding about this with http://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/teaching/Topology10/Notes.pdf. On page 51, it illustrates to me why the one point compactification in topology is usually gluing something " ....we can think of this process as bringing the two ends of the interval together to meet at the point $\infty$...." and the example given in session 3.6.4 there. In our case, the neighborhoods of the one new point is a ("sub"-)torus around the inner circle $\cup \{\infty\}$, we can think of this process as bringing the inner circle to the point of $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is that we can think the homeomorphism as a deformation with continuity and without gluing.[Is it correct to think about homeomorphisms as deformations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493075/is-it-correct-to-think-about-homeomorphisms-as-deformations) Then we can know the open annulus $\{(x,y):1<x^2+y^2<2\}$ homeomorphic to the surface of the ball but without the South Pole and the North Pole.

One point compactification is often viewed as a process gluing things together. You would get some sense about this by taking a look at the notes here and read through the examples given there.(p51 and section 3.6.4) They have intuitive graphs there.

http://www.math.colostate.edu/~renzo/teaching/Topology10/Notes.pdf